# Система ХП по ячейкам в Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Делаю **изометрическую** игру и решил реализовать ХП в виде куба, **три** грани которого будут ячейками здоровья (пример на первом скрине) с возможностью добавлять целую ячейку в будущем при прокачке.

[Фулл](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9EK1.png)

[Первое получение урона](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziBtc.png)

[Второе получение урона](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axnZj.png)

[Ну вы поняли](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkfie.png)

Ну и что бы в будущем можно было добавить красивые анимации убывания и восполнения отдельной грани.

Я пока нашёл только 1 вариант реализации, это сделать заготовленные **n** ячеек на весь экран, где в основной 4 состояния ***(3/3, 2/3, 1/3 и 0/3)*** и отображать текущее количество нужных ячеек, остальные деактивировать, а активный "куб" который получает урон или восполняет здоровье перемещать на нужную ячейку, но если так делать то получится большое нагромождение из **свича с 9-ю кейсами** и самое главное - таким образом пропадает возможность анимации отдельно каждой грани.

Понимаю что может я пытаюсь прыгнуть выше головы и это излишне, но может кто сталкивался или имеет идеи как это красиво реализовать?

Comment: Деление на 3, всё гениальное просто, но я не догадался XD
Спасибо большое, это будет шикарно!

Answer (score 0):

Если куб, это просто растровый Image на `Canvas'е`, то у картинок есть свойство `"Image type"`, и у типа `"Filled"` пункт `"Fill method"`.

[image: Вот]

Можно наложить картинку в цвете на обесцвеченную и за каждое потерянное очко здоровья отнимать треть от `"Fill amount"` (хотя правильнее, наверное, будет что-то типа: `image.fillAmount = health / 3f`). Геометрия твоего куба вполне позволяет провернуть эту аферу.

Думаю, это можно и красиво анимировать при желании.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).